# Page counter "lost in translation"

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, counters

I am writing a translation; on each page I would like to display the page number(s) of the original.

I have introduced a counter `origpagecounter` and I set it to the new value whenever there is a new page in the original, e.g. `\setcounter{origpagecounter}{124}`.

I can display the current value of the counter in the header, say, with `\fancyhead[R]{\arabic{origpagecounter}}`.

This works ok, but it displays the (last) value that is defined on the current page.

How can I access the last counter from the previous page to make it show the range of the pages that went into the current page, viz. `123--124`, instead of just `124`?

Comment: counters can have only one value at a time. The `\arabic{origpagecounter}` just uses the current value, and no other one. Either use two counters or a different approach. You need an `olderorigpagecounter` most likely!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- that's indeed my question: how can I access the last counter from the previous page

Comment: I'll try to provide a solution

Comment: you can probably use a mark. Using a counter directly in the header isn't a good idea anyway as it can be wrong due to the asynchronous pagebuilder. But you should make a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using marks, I would add `\mark{124}` at the beginning and end of the original page 124 (attached to the first and last word so a pagebreak doesn't occur between the material and the mark). Then the header should use `\firstmark--\botmark` to get all the pages that contribute material to the current page.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. For the reference, I made the macro `\newcommand{\origpagebreak}{\mark{\arabic{origpagecounter}}\addtocounter{origpagecounter}{1}\mark{\arabic{origpagecounter}}}` to indicate where page breaks appears in the original, and then `\firstmark--\botmark` in the header. This seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Only a preliminary version, that stores the original page counter.

One could check also for equal pages, i.e. a translation might be longer in one language than in another one so that takes more pages than the corresponding original version, it's still valid.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{oldorigpagecounter}
\newcounter{origpagecounter}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[R]{%
  \ifnum\value{oldorigpagecounter}>0% Only for later pages 
  \arabic{oldorigpagecounter} -- \arabic{origpagecounter}%
  \setcounter{oldorigpagecounter}{\value{origpagecounter}}%
  \else
  \arabic{origpagecounter}%
  \fi
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}


\setcounter{oldorigpagecounter}{123}
\setcounter{origpagecounter}{124}
\blindtext[2]
\clearpage
\setcounter{origpagecounter}{125}
\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I don't know where the pagebreak will occur in the translated text. Ideally, I need to save the current `origpagecounter` into `oldorigpagecounter` automatically at the beginning of each (translation-)page.

Comment: @user66081: Well, please provide your document then ... it's only a suggestion by my side so far. I can't know your setup in advance! You have to specify however which is the original page counter anyway for each portion of your translated text